# update a formular, redundancy of the result

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-security

im using spring MVC and im trying to upload a formular, but when changing the informations, im getting 2 versions, the old and the new one. how to keep the new one only ? please help me

here is the code of the act

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/saveCli")
public String saveCli(@Valid Client c,BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        model.addAttribute("clients",metier.listClients());
        return ("creerClient");
    }
    if(c.getIdClient()!=null){
    metier.modifierClient(c);

    }else

    metier.ajouterClient(c);
    model.addAttribute("client", new Client());
    model.addAttribute("clients",metier.listClients());
    return "creerClient";

}
```

btw creerclient is the name of the vue

Comment: no, this is only spring MVC with jsp pages

Comment: im sorry, i did not pay attetion